# Mocha: Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

Tags: unit-testing, http, mocha.js, sinon, axios

I have written a small interceptor using `axios` that would flush out `localBrowserStorage` and would redirect user to login page if response code is 401. 
It works fine but I am getting some errors in the unit test.

**Test**

```
describe('Api Service', () => {
  let sandbox;

  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  describe.only('interceptors', () => {
    it('clear storage and redirect to login if response status code is 401', (done) => {
      moxios.withMock(() => {
        sandbox.spy(browserHistory, 'push');
        sandbox.spy(storage, 'clear');

        axios.get('/test');

        moxios.wait(() => {
          const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
          request.respondWith({
            status: 401,
            response: {}
          }).then(() => {
            expect(browserHistory.push).to.have.been.calledWith('/login');
            expect(storage.clear).to.have.been.called; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions
            done();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I get these two warnings with this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Request failed with status code 401
(node:5338) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): AssertionError: expected push to have been called with arguments /login
```

And this error:
`Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

**EDIT:**

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (response.status === 401) {
    storage.clear();
    browserHistory.push('/login');
    return response;
  }
  return response;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass rejections back to Mocha by calling `done` in the `catch` handler:

```
request.respondWith({
  status: 401,
  response: {}
}).then(() => {
  expect(browserHistory.push).to.have.been.calledWith('/login');
  expect(storage.clear).to.have.been.called; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions
  done();
}).catch(done);
```

If you don't handle rejected promises, there is a chance that `done` never gets called (resulting in a timeout).

For instance, if one of the expectations fails, it will throw an error. When that happens, the call to `done` following the expectation lines will never get executed. You can (and should) catch the error with a `.catch` clause, as above. That should call `done` with the error. The code I'm using is short for:

```
.catch(function(err) {
  done(err);
})
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more so that I understand this completely for future references? Also, doing  what you told it doesn't call the `spies` and the test fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: And it still throws a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Comment: @Umair which one?

Comment: I have updated question with the piece of code that I am actually testing. After what you have specified in your answer, the test fail and it throws an error that says it doesn't call `browserHistory.push` or `storage.clear`. Also, the warning `(node:5935) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Request failed with status code 401
` doesn't go away.

Comment: @Umair so your test fails because your expectations fail. That's what testing is for. I'm unsure why you get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`; I assumed it gets thrown by `request.respondWith()` but perhaps it doesn't. I don't know `moxios` so it may have to do with that.

Comment: Yeah probably. Thanks a lot. I will look into this myself. However, I am thankful for clearing out my concept with handling rejected promises.